# neo4j-nodes label with MERGE

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have created graph using `MERGE` to avoid repetition, following is the query

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
     FROM "file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/file.csv" 
     AS network
MERGE (sourceNode {id:network.node1})
MERGE (destNode {id:network.node2})
WITH sourceNode, 
     destNode, 
     network
```

It doesn't assign labels to nodes but I need labels to query graph. Is there any way to assign labels to nodes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to miss the variables which are supposed to be assigned to a node before the labels.This way your nodes will be assigned labels and you can use their respective variables for operations on them. I've modified the query. Hope this helps!

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
 FROM "file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/file.csv" 
 AS network
MERGE (n:sourceNode {id:network.node1})
MERGE (m:destNode {id:network.node2})
WITH n,m,network
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, seems that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help. Please do read the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/) thoroughly. It will help you a lot in the future as you continue with neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review the developer guide. [Here's how to create a node with a label](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/#create-create-a-node-with-a-label). However, if you want to set a label dynamically, such as from a CSV, then you will need to use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) for this, as it is not supported natively by Cypher.